# Set a custom title to a named-export Story

Tags: storybook

How do you give a `title` value to an individual story in storybook?

Seems like it should be `storyname.title = 'value'` but that doesn't work.

### For example:

```
export default {
  title: "Root Component Title",
  component: SomeComponent,
};

export const SomeComponentVariant = () => <SetUpTwoFAContainer />;
// This title does not work
SomeComponentVariant.title = "Set Up Parent Container";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rename the exported **const** from `SomeComponentVariant` to `SetUpParentContainer` and the story will be rendered with the title *"Set Up Parent Container"*:

[image]

Comment: `storyName` has no effect for me.

Comment: @martin - please state your exact Storybook version, because *"for me"* is not a version :)

Comment: Since 7.0.0. Right now I have 7.4.0

Answer (score 2):

You can override the story name using `SomeComponentVariant.storyName = '...'`  to match the component name.

StorybookJS Docs [source](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/naming-components-and-hierarchy#single-story-hoisting)

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: Works on 6.5.16

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is `SomeComponentVariant.storyName`